# Benefits of virtualization if only one server on hardware

Tags: virtualization

A big HANA server will sit **alone** on dedicated hardware, nearly hundred processors, 2 TB of ram.
The customer insists on having VMware between the iron and the DB. Most of the advantages of virtualization is related to having several separate servers on the same hardware, this is not the case here. The disadvantages remain.

Any benefits?

Comment: What are these "disadvantages" you speak of?

Comment: If you are using a hundred processors and 2 TB of RAM, be prepared to cash out some Big Money to VMware... whose pricing is based on how much hardware you throw at it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Isolation. You can handle backups "easier" and you can move to another machine for maintenance and have no issues with drivers in the image.

These all are minor issues - really minor. Unless the customer wants the "future flexibility" there is no real logical reason for this. It likely runs down to some policy made without too much brain intervention and applied without any more  brain intervention.

THAT SAID: maybe the customer wants the chance to run some smaller VM's on that machine. Not always, but having the ability to move other VM's to that host (even if rescaling the HANA instance down) can come in handy during disaster situations. This is not relevant for large operations but for smaller setups it can be a nice last line of defense.

Comment: Personally I think the ability to move a VM to new hardware is a really huge reason for making a "trivial" VM (i.e., a host with only one VM on it). That way you can take advantage of a hardware upgrade without having to rebuild or migrate anything.